# Passar uma variável do método construtor para outro método

Tags: php, php-7, cakephp-2

Estou usando PDO e Quero um método construtor com a conexão com o banco de dados mas a variável da conexão não esta acessível em outro método

class Estoque{

```
public function __construct(){
    $conn= new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=caixa","root","");

}


public function listarTodosProdutos(){// seleciona todos produtos do Banco de dados e retorna

    $stmt=$conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM produtos");
    $stmt->execute();
    while($result = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
        echo"Codigo:".$result["id"]." "."<br>"."Nome do Produto:   "."<b>".$result["nome"]."<br>"."</b>"." de valor de    ".$result["valor"]." Reais "."<br>"."da categoria    ".$result["descricao"]."</b>"."<br>"."---------------------------------------------------"."<br>";

    }
```

}

aqui esta a outra parte que instancio e chamo o método

```
<?php
require_once"Estoque.php";

$e=new Estoque();
$e->listarTodosProdutos();
```

?>

Erro apresentado

Notice: Undefined variable: conn in C:\xampp\htdocs\Caixa made in Gabriel\Estoque.php on line

Comment: Use `$this->conn`

Answer (score 0):

Variáveis instanciadas localmente porém que servem para a classe todas devem ser chamadas com

**$this->variável_que_deseja**

No seu caso $this->conn

Comment: eu mudei coloquei o $this->  no modo construtor e continua aparecendo   aparecendo o mesmo erro Notice: Undefined variable: conn in C:\xampp\htdocs\Caixa made in Gabriel\Estoque.php on line 8              e                            Notice: Undefined variable: conn in C:\xampp\htdocs\Caixa made in Gabriel\Estoque.php on line

Comment: Tente algo dessa maneira, declarando uma variavel, e logo apos sobrescrevendo seu valor com o valor do construtor
public $conn;


  public function __construct($conn) {

    $this->conn = $conn;

  }

Answer (score 0):

Exatamente como disseram a solução é colocar o $this na instancia e na atribuição que torna-se uma variável global

```
    class Estoque{
```

public function __construct(){
    $this->conn= new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=caixa","root","");

}

public function listarTodosProdutos(){// seleciona todos produtos do Banco de dados e retorna

`$stmt=$this->conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM produtos");
$stmt->execute();
while($result = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
    echo"Codigo:".$result["id"]." "."<br>"."Nome do Produto:   "."<b>".$result["nome"]."<br>"."</b>"." de valor de    ".$result["valor"]." Reais "."<br>"."da categoria    ".$result["descricao"]."</b>"."<br>"."---------------------------------------------------"."<br>";

}`

}

aqui esta a outra parte que instancio e chamo o método

listarTodosProdutos();
?>